# Windows git, error moving to remote drive other than Z

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

This issue happens in Git-Bash when cd-ing to a remote Windows drive other than /z

To reproduce:

Mount a remote windows drive "Z:\" and another such as "T:\ or Y:\"

Open a new git bash instance:

`$cd /c` --this works

`$cd /z` --this works fine

`$cd /y` --this fails

Is there a workaround to add more than one remote drive? or is this a bug with the git-bash shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this by just cd-ing straight into the directory (d'oh)

```
$ cd //mountedDrive/my/path
```